# How i can install Actor Platform with Docker

Tags: scala, docker, akka, actor-platform

I am trying to install Actor Platform with Docker. How I can do this? I can't find this in docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of Actor Platform here.

You need to run Postgres container and run actor-server container linked with Postgres:

```
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password> -d postgres
docker run --rm -e DB_PASSWORD=<password> --link postgres:postgres -p 9070:9070 -p 9080:9080 -p 9090:9090 actor/actor-server:latest
```